# Error message "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles..."

Tags: civievent, profile

I am using civicrm 4.7 on Joomla and I'm trying to expose a profile through the joomla menu system but I am getting this error message:

"Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type."

I am trying to provide my staff with the option to see participant detail by selecting the profile from the Joomla menu. I've attached screen shots of my settings. As far as I know all the data attached to the participant record type. Is this correct?

[image]
[image]

Comment: No screenshot showing, but yes, double check that your fields are for only a  single record type. that said, if you are saying you are including participant fields, then i might be surprised if this is available to you just as a standalone profile, rather than only being available within the context of Event registrations

Comment: Ah screenshots now.

Comment: When you say single record type, do you mean only from the participant table?

Comment: i don't think you can use Participant based profile for a general 'search' profile. happy to be told i am wrong. but to my mind, participant data belongs to participant records which are associated with an Event, and if you don't have the ability to specify which event etc then you won't get what you want on a standalone type profile. you might want to re-ask the question such as 'how can i provide a search screen that will .........."